# why can't i run meteor in root mode?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, meteor, root

I am installing meteor by shell script in root mode. When I try to build app it is prompting

*You are attempting to run Meteor as the "root" user. If you are developing, this is almost certainly *not* what you want to do and will likely result in incorrect file
permissions. However, if you are running this in a build process (CI, etc.) or you are absolutely sure you know what you are doing, add the `--unsafe-perm` flag to
this command to proceed.*

I am running other things with shell script which needs root mode. Any help appreciated

Answer (score -2):

You are attempting to run Meteor as the "root" user.

If you are developing, this is almost certainly not what you want to do and will likely result in incorrect file permissions.

However, if you are running this in a build process (CI, etc.) or you are absolutely sure you know what you are doing, add the

```
--unsafe-perm
```

flag to this command to proceed.

Comment: Respect, an answer quoting only the question - do you think OP will understand it better when *you* write it?

Comment: You can downvote as you like. But I doesn't change the fact, that the answer is already in the question.

Comment: is it because of latest version of meteor? i used the same script to build meteor app previously it worked in root mode.

Comment: can't you just add the flag mentioned when running meteor?

Comment: Another option is to use sudo -u username in your script (sudo doesn't have to be used for elevating privileges)

Comment: With latest version 1.4.2 in root mode we cannot run meteor in root, but in 1.4.1 it is working, probably I need to change my code accordingly, since running meteor in root mode is not recommendable.